How can we update the drag image with DnD API?
I am currently working on a drag and drop feature on a web application and I would like to add a visual helper when the user click on ctrl or alt button like google drive do :

It doesn't seem we can change the drag image set in dragstart event. So how can we do that ?
Thanks in advance

The HTML Drag and Drop API has its own functionality when it comes to the modifier keys (like Ctrl, Alt etc.). It is called the dropEffect property, and it changes the cursor according to the keys that are pressed while you are dragging something. Notice that this depends on the OS that the user is running.
The main issue (achieving what you ask for) is that the drag and drop API is blocking the events coursed by the user pressing the keys. The dropEffect will change if you press Ctrl, but no events are fired (try the following example; start to drag and the press Ctrl -- nothing happens -- the background should change to beige). On top of that the Alt key as a special function in regard to a draggable element, in that, if you press and hold the Alt key the text in the element will be selectable.
So, the following example shows the limitations. I use the setDragImage() method to change the default drag image. It is identical to the default drag image except if you press Ctrl before the dragstart event, the drag image will have an "ctrl icon" on the right side (the drag image is painted outside the view in the offscreen element). And, yes, the drag image can only be set in the dragstart callback function...
Conclusion is that you need some custom drag and drop functionality if you would like to control both the drag image and the modifier keys at the same time.


const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
const offscreen = document.getElementById('offscreen');

ul.addEventListener('dragstart', e => {
  let li = e.target.closest('li');
  offscreen.innerHTML = li.outerHTML;
  let clone = offscreen.querySelector('li');
  e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(clone, 0, 0);
});

document.addEventListener('dragover', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
});

document.addEventListener('drop', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.body.className = '';
});

document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if(e.key == 'Control' || e.key == 'Alt'){
    document.body.classList.add(e.key.toLowerCase());
  }
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  if(e.key == 'Control' || e.key == 'Alt'){
    document.body.classList.remove(e.key.toLowerCase());
  }
});
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  gap: .2em;
}

li {
  border: tomato solid thin;
  border-radius: .2em;
  display: block;
  height: 3em;
}

span.pdf::before {
  content: '';
}

li>span {
  background-color: tomato;
  padding: .2em;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul#offscreen {
  position: absolute;
  left: -500px;
}

ul#offscreen span {
  position: relative;
}

body.control ul#offscreen span::after {
  content: 'Ctrl';
  position: absolute;
  right: -1em;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}

body.control {
  background-color: Beige;
}
<ul>
  <li draggable="true"><span class="pdf">Getting stated</span></li>
  <li draggable="true"><span class="pdf">Something else</span></li>
</ul>
<ul id="offscreen"></ul>




Thanks for the clarification. But I still want to know how GDrive did it, you can press the modifiers whenever you want and the element will update. I guess they are creating a new element which follows the mouse ? I'll look into it

@Phoste I guess they are not using the Drag and Drop API. You can implement your own drag and drop functionality in JavaScript (or somebody could write an example) or maybe find a JavaScript library that support the features that you need.
